# The root.disk file is empty (0 KB)

Tags: 12.04, grub2, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu 12.04 (Wubi) not starting - root.disk corrupted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228709/ubuntu-12-04-wubi-not-starting-root-disk-corrupted)

I've a problem when starting ubuntu..its showing like this:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible
command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>
```

I've installed Ubuntu on Windows platform with Wubi... I checked the `root.disk` file in `/ubuntu/disks/` It is `0KB` in size. I'm wondering whether my data is lost. Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: You seem to have deleted ( or Windows lost ) your Ubuntu, so you will need to reinstall.