# WUBI 12.04 hangs on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wubi

After looking around this site for a while I can't seem to find a working solution for WUBI.  So I installed Ubuntu 12.04 the other day via a WUBI install with Windows 7 Home Premium, giving it 18 GB.  It worked perfectly fine up until now but it consistently hangs on startup now.  Specifically, after selecting Ubuntu in the options for OS's it goes to the purple screen, waits a moment and then displays "Ubuntu" with the 5 white dots below it.  The dots fill in orange one-by-one, and then the system hangs.  We have tried to leave it to see if it boots but it seems to never leave that screen (up until now it took 30 seconds or so).  Windows still starts up without issue.

There has been one exception where it did boot up but after logging in it displayed one monitor as black and my primary monitor had a single purple bar along the top, the only way to get it to turn off was to force shut down by holding the power button.

Additional details are:
Windows 7 Home Premium for our primary OS, NVidea GeForce 550 GTX Titanium overclocked (On ubuntu we installed the latest "stable" driver but there is a newer version however it hasnt affected previous startups in any way), Intel i3 3.07 GHz Processor, and I'm not sure if we have the Grub, Grub 2, or Grub legacy boot loader.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

After posting this question I tried again just to see if it would somehow just magically fix, but it seems to have degraded.  It now does not even attempt to start Ubuntu, it instead displays the 2 lines

Try (hd0,0) NTFS5: No Bubildr

Try (hd0,1) NTFS5: error; "prefix" is not set

And then it moves to a new screen with:

GNU GRUB VERSION 1.49-21ubuntu3.9

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.  For the first work, TAB lists possible command completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

Grub>

So it apparently is waiting for some BASH commands but I am not sure how to use this (if you are supposed to) in order to fix it.  I assume based on the "no Bildr" and prefix thing that my boot loader is broken.

Comment: You need to boot with `nomodeset` with an nvidia graphics card. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Likely now the `root.disk` is corrupted due to the hanging and hard shutdowns. You should run `chkdsk /f` and reinstall unless you want to try to recover: http://askubuntu.com/questions/228709/ubuntu-12-04-wubi-not-starting-root-disk-corrupted

Comment: Thanks, I ran the chkdsk and your hunch was right.  Following those links you gave everything seems to be running well.