# Grub Menu opens on boot

Tags: grub2, kernel

Just recently, I installed Ubuntu on my laptop. I am dual booting ubuntu along side of Windows 7, in which ubuntu is dedicated 22 GB and Windows is dedicated the rest. So like the normal startup, you select either Ubuntu or 7 and the OS's boot is launched from there. However, within the last couple of days, when I select Ubuntu to boot with, it opens a GRUB menu. Here are the commands I've tried to enter in sequence, which was unsuccessful.

```
grub>ls
grub>set root=(hd0,msdos3)
grub>linux /vmlinuz ro root=/dev/sda1
   "File /vmlinuz not found."
grub>Initrd /initrd.img
     "You must load the kernel first."
grub>boot
    "You must load the kernel first."
```

I obtained this list of commands from an outside website, and honestly haven't really ever used grub before, so I don't really know what I'm doing. Especially considering I'm not quite familiar with Linux yet. So please try to dumb it down for me if you can.

So basically two questions come up: What happened to /vmlinuz and how do I load the kernel?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: HP G62, Intel Dual Core 2.3 GHz SSE2, 3 GB RAM, SP1, 64 bit OS (Windows)

Comment: I am not sure of this so I ask it first. What is the output of "cat /etc/default/grub | grep "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT"" ? Normally it is "quiet splash".

Comment: Oh srr I forgot you can't boot ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know which partition you installed on. In those instructions you listed, you're setting root to `/dev/sda3` to load the kernel, and then saying that root is `/dev/sda1`. Which is normally used if you have a separate boot partition on `/dev/sda3` with `/` (root) on `/dev/sda1` - either that or you're entering instructions from the website without understanding how they apply to your setup - because this isn't a normal setup.

That first menu you see - are you sure it's a Grub menu or is this in fact a Wubi install and it's really a Windows Boot Manager screen. i.e. did you install from within windows? (because that matters).

If it's a Windows boot manager, then you need to check this out: [Ubuntu 12.04 (Wubi) not starting - root.disk corrupted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228709/ubuntu-12-04-wubi-not-starting-root-disk-corrupted)

This answer was too long for comments (even though I'm asking for clarification), but you should edit your question with more information and the comment when you're done. Then I'll either delete this or adjust the answer as required.