# Migrating root.disk problem

Tags: installation, wubi, migration

My ubuntu 11.10 got corrupted today. I had installed it using wubi installer I copied root.disk file from there.

Now I installed ubuntu 11.10 using wubi on different computer.Can I use my older    root.disk under this wubi install on my new computer.

I replaced my newer root.disk with older one but it doesn't work.
Help me fast.

Comment: What doesn't work? You get any error message?

Comment: @salem "no such device found:<deviceid>" and 'no such file found press any key to continue.."

Comment: If you describe how it got corrupted, maybe you can fix that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/228709/ubuntu-12-04-wubi-not-starting-root-disk-corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Is the `root.disk` backed up from before the corruption? If not it won't work. It it is (a good copy), then you need to change the UUID to boot. So the first time, hit <kbd>C</kbd> to get to a Grub command prompt and enter:

```
search -s -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $root
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

This will boot the Wubi install (provided it's good, as I mentioned). Then you just need to update the grub.cfg to get it working normally:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: how i can get the UUID of older root.disk....

Comment: It's the UUID of the old NTFS partition. But `grub.cfg` *within* the `root.disk` uses it to boot and it needs to refer to the new partition.

Comment: Is there any command in grub command prompt to get UUID of my older root.disk.

Comment: I got error "no device found:OEA2FFODA2FEF853" on my new computer after I replaced newer root.disk file with older one. Is that the UUID of my older root.disk file.

Comment: It's not the UUID of the `root.disk`. It's the UUID of the old partition that is stored on the `root.disk`.

Comment: Thanks @bcbc for your precious time...but I am still there, ok as you said it is the UUID of old partition stored under root.disk. So my question is how can I find the UUID of my old partition stored under root.disk. My root.disk is healthy and is of 19.2 GB.

Comment: @AathaarvSingh you find it by [loop mounting it](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_access_my_Wubi_install_and_repair_my_install_if_it_won.27t_boot.3F) and looking in the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. But if you want to change it, it's easier to boot as I showed in my answer and run `sudo update-grub`.