# Ubuntu not booting any more after a clean windows 7 shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7, wubi, ntfs

I had installed **Ubuntu 12.04** from **Windows 7** using **wubi.exe**.

For more than 8 months It was running fine. Today I booted into windows 7 then I shut it down properly and tried to boot **Ubuntu**. I started getting following error.

> Try (hd0,0): NTFS5: No wubildr Try (hd0,1): 
>   Try (hd0,1): NTFS5: error "prefix" is not set

I booted windows again, before booting it ran a disk check `chkdsk` automatically and I noticed that it has deleted `swap.disk` and `root.disk` files from the NTFS partition labeled `ForUB`

> I greatly appreciate any help to get my Ubuntu OS & files back.

I had pulled the log content of this event and it is as follows:

```
Checking file system on E:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is ForUB.


One of your disks needs to be checked for consistency. You
may cancel the disk check, but it is strongly recommended
that you continue.
Windows will now check the disk.                         

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
The record length 0x2b0 is too large for attribute of type 0x80
and instance tag 0x4 in file 0x204.  The maximum value is 0x150.
Truncating badly linked attribute records
from file record segment 516.
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 128 in file 516.
Unable to locate attribute of type 0x80, lowest vcn 0x0,
instance tag 0x4 in file 0x204.
The first attribute of type 0x30 and instance tag 0x0
in file 0x204 should not be resident.
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 48 in file 516.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x3 and segment
reference 0x2000000000204.  The expected attribute type is 0x30.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (48, "")
from file record segment 516.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x4000000000209.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 521.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x300000000020a.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 522.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x600000000020b.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 523.
  768 file records processed.                                          File verification completed.
  1 large file records processed.                                      0 bad file records processed.                                        0 EA records processed.                                              0 reparse records processed.                                       CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
There is no DOS file name attribute in file 0x204.
Correcting minor file name errors in file 516.
Unable to locate the file name attribute of index entry root.disk
of index $I30 with parent 0x1de in file 0x204.
Deleting index entry root.disk in index $I30 of file 478.
Unable to locate the file name attribute of index entry ROOT~1.DIS
of index $I30 with parent 0x1de in file 0x204.
Deleting index entry ROOT~1.DIS in index $I30 of file 478.
Index entry swap.disk of index $I30 in file 0x1de points to unused file 0x205.
Deleting index entry swap.disk in index $I30 of file 478.
Index entry SWAP~1.DIS of index $I30 in file 0x1de points to unused file 0x205.
Deleting index entry SWAP~1.DIS in index $I30 of file 478.
  936 index entries processed.                                         Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
  1 unindexed files scanned.                                         Recovering orphaned file root.disk (516) into directory file 478.
  0 unindexed files recovered.                                       CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
  768 file SDs/SIDs processed.                                         Cleaning up 6 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 6 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 6 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
Inserting data attribute into file 516.
  85 data files processed.                                            CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the
master file table (MFT) bitmap.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the volume bitmap.
Windows has made corrections to the file system.

 104857599 KB total disk space.
   2168536 KB in 398 files.
       124 KB in 86 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
     69923 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 102619016 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  26214399 total allocation units on disk.
  25654754 allocation units available on disk.

Internal Info:
00 03 00 00 ef 01 00 00 5f 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........_.......
01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

---

**Update**: After this If I try to boot Ubuntu. It Just loads grub and stops with prompt as follows:

> grub>

---

The central file system control structure of the NTFS file system is the Master File Table. So the above event modified it.

Is there any one who tried to read and edit the MTF?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to do a new instalation again.

Comment: @LnxSlck: I really need some of the files which were on that disk. Any hints on solution?

Comment: Are you able to do a sucessfull chkdsk? After that when you boot to Ubuntu what erros do you get? It stops where?

Comment: @LnxSlck: Updated in the question accordingly... Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling GRUB? Booting from a live cd, chrooting your environment and reinstalling grub?

Comment: If chkdsk deleted the root.disk, you'll need to recover it first before you can boot Ubuntu. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/228709/ubuntu-12-04-wubi-not-starting-root-disk-corrupted PS don't reinstall Grub - it will do nothing other than stop Windows from booting